# Capture replays in Team Fortress 2 without QuickTime

Tags: team-fortress-2

In order to save Replays in TF2, one needs Quicktime. I have several other codecs installed on my system, is there any way to make TF2 use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to force TF2 onto a completely different codec. Valve have said in a forum post a while back that they will look into whether they can come up with a different solution for Windows users, but for now we are stuck with it.

**However**, according to [this Steam Community Guide](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=22253906&postcount=6), you can use [Quicktime Alternative](https://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/?url=http://www.free-codecs.com/download/quicktime_alternative.htm) instead of installing Quicktime. It's a set of free codecs for playing/watching Quicktime video without Quicktime, and apparently works with TF2. (**Use at your own risk**):